# a regex to match a string representing optgroup and option tags

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to match a string that represents optgroup and option tag using one reg ex. The aim is to have a match hierarchy that can be used to build a hash where each key represents an optgroup value and each value is an array of options.

the string looks like this:

```
group: group1
option1
option2
option3
group: group2
option1
option2
option3
```

I got as far as this reg ex:

```
/(?<=group:\s)(([^\n]+(?))([\S\s]*?)(?=group:\s|\z))/gm
```

It matches first each `group`, i.e. everything between two `group:` strings incl. the first `group:` but excluding the second. It then matches as subgroup the name of the optgroup. In this case `group1`.

But I can't seem to be able to come up with a pattern that would match each of the following lines individually.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Mostly you will need to use `\K` and `\G`. The only problem I see is the following: How will you distinguish options from group 1 and group 2 if you match options individually? My 2 cents: use 2 regexes

Comment: I will be using ruby 1.9
Two regexes are of couse possible I hoped to optimize this using just one
I hoped to distinguish the options by restricting them into submatches of the above regex. That way I could just build my hash from the returned matches and submatches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting but I don't think the regular expressions can handle this. The groups represents strings, not lists. If a group is contained in a part of the pattern that matched multiple times, the last match is returned.

So even if you write it correctly ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/nC3oO9/1)):

```
(?<=group:\s)(.*)((?:\n)(?!group:).*)*
```

The capturing groups will contain:

```
('group1', 'option3')
```

You can either use two regular expressions, one to match the entire group and ont to match the lines, or if you pattern is so simple, use a regex that match the full group and then split the lines.

Comment: I was already thinking that this might be something not possible to achieve in a regex. But thanks for correcting my regex. I will leave this open for another bit, maybe someone has this amazing trick that does what I want, but otherwise I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I benchmarked a little in ruby and it turned out that it is faster to first split the string with a simple regex to capture the groups and later postprocess the group strings using ruby functions.